# Download Manager not working right - nothing happen after click download button

Tags: java, android, android-studio, download, download-manager

I have problem like in title: Download Manager not working right - I want download file .apk but after click button nothing happens. In logcat I have no errors or warrnings, it not works on emulator and phone as well.

I tried all examples from here(but not only) [Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog) - and still downloading .apk is not starting.

My code:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import java.net.URI;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private String url =  "https://someurl.com/appplication.apk";
    Button btnDownload;
    private static final int PERMISSION_STORAGE_CODE = 1000;

    private int downloadedProgress = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnDownload = findViewById(R.id.btnDownload);

        btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                    if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                        requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_STORAGE_CODE);

                    } else {
                        startDownloading();
                    }
                } else {
                    startDownloading();
                }
            }
        });

    }
    private void startDownloading(){
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE
                | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
        request.setTitle("Download");
        request.setDescription("Downloading file...");

        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "" + System.currentTimeMillis());

        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        manager.enqueue(request);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch(requestCode){
            case PERMISSION_STORAGE_CODE: {
                if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    startDownloading();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied...!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: does it work if you remove `setAllowedNetworkTypes`?

Comment: Testing on Android Q   ?

Comment: `setAllowedNetworkTypes` - it not works.

Testing on Android Pie